# catkin_make error while building rospackage (beginner tutorial)

Tags: catkin-make

[image: Rosanswers logo]

here is the link to the tutorial
i get the following errors

```
surya@surya-Aspire-V5-571:~/catkin_ws$ catkin_make
Base path: /home/surya/catkin_ws
Source space: /home/surya/catkin_ws/src
Build space: /home/surya/catkin_ws/build
Devel space: /home/surya/catkin_ws/devel
Install space: /home/surya/catkin_ws/install
####
#### Running command: "make cmake_check_build_system" in "/home/surya/catkin_ws/build"
####
-- Using CATKIN_DEVEL_PREFIX: /home/surya/catkin_ws/devel
-- Using CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH: /home/surya/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- This workspace overlays: /home/surya/catkin_ws/devel;/opt/ros/hydro
-- Using PYTHON_EXECUTABLE: /usr/bin/python
-- Python version: 2.7
-- Using Debian Python package layout
-- Using CATKIN_ENABLE_TESTING: ON
-- Call enable_testing()
-- Using CATKIN_TEST_RESULTS_DIR: /home/surya/catkin_ws/build/test_results
-- Found gtest sources under '/usr/src/gtest': gtests will be built
-- catkin 0.5.86
-- BUILD_SHARED_LIBS is on
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- ~~  traversing 1 packages in topological order:
-- ~~  - beginner_tututorials
-- ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
-- +++ processing catkin package: 'beginner_tututorials'
-- ==> add_subdirectory(beginner_tututorials)
CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package roscpy.

  Set roscpy_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  roscpy.  The file will have one of the following names:

    roscpyConfig.cmake
    roscpy-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  beginner_tututorials/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


CMake Error at /opt/ros/hydro/share/catkin/cmake/catkinConfig.cmake:72 (find_package):
  Could not find a configuration file for package std_msg.

  Set std_msg_DIR to the directory containing a CMake configuration file for
  std_msg.  The file will have one of the following names:

    std_msgConfig.cmake
    std_msg-config.cmake

Call Stack (most recent call first):
  beginner_tututorials/CMakeLists.txt:7 (find_package)


-- Configuring incomplete, errors occurred!
make: *** [cmake_check_build_system] Error 1
Invoking "make cmake_check_build_system" failed
surya@surya-Aspire-V5-571:~/catkin_ws$
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/156696/catkin_make-error-while-building-rospackage-(beginner-tutorial)/) by [Surya_Deopa](https://answers.ros.org/users/15136/surya_deopa/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-04-23

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I believe you have just made some typos, the errors above are coming up because the build system cannot find `roscpy` and `std_msg`, which is probably because they should be `rospy` and `std_msgs`, respectively.

I think if you update your `CMakeLists.txt` to fix these typos, then it should work for you.

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2014-04-23

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [robo_lady](https://answers.ros.org/users/29072/robo_lady/) on 2017-01-16**:
don't forget to also update your package.xml file